# how do a i do a highlight bar

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor

I was doing a project for a movie website and I have no idea how to make a bar similar to the one shown here, which tag helper is used for that, will I have to make a partial page? or another process?

[image: first]
[image: seconde]

Comment: Hi del, as far as I know, there is no tag helper that can directly achieve the effect you want. It needs to be combined with others according to the specific situation you want, so I want to confirm with you whether you want to display the highlight when you click the tag, and whether the page will be executed. What about the corresponding jump? Or the page does not jump, just the current page display content changes? If I imagine the situation is not what you want, can you tell me what situation you want?

Comment: Can you share with me your relevant code for this situation? That will help us solve the question faster.